# Access functions inside controllers angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to access functions which are defined as $scope functions but are defined inside controller ? If I define function which is used somewhere above in the code, it is not accessible. Can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: And your code is? You want to access which function, from where?

Comment: Sorry, it's not really clear what do you mean. Are the "functions" defined as $scope or controller methods? Can you please share some code snippets as well?

Comment: I want to access controller methods inide $scope methods.

Comment: You've been asked twice to post your code. Do it. No code, no help.

Comment: I have problem with $ sign but i try to post code here

Comment: after posting code nobody replied.

Answer (score 0):

here is example code:

```
App.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.init = function () {
    $scope.funcVal = functionA();
},

$scope.init();

functionA = function() {
var a = 10;
},

}]);
```